# Connect SuperType and SubType

Tags: sql, database, oracle, entity-relationship

I have to connect Supertype Entity Called

```
Product ( prod_ID (PK) , description , price , type, typeId )
```

to the following subtypes :

```
Footwear ( typeId(PK, fk), Brandname, Style)

Apparels ( typeId(PK,fk), material, size)
```

Here each product is either foot wear or apparels which is mentioned in the "type" column. Many products can have the same type and Type id's. How do I connect the superType with subTypes ? As Type id is not unique in the product table , I couldn't use it as a primary key in subtypes.

Comment: `supertype_owner` and `supertype_name` in `user_types` should do it. But I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I tried to connect the tables as "create table footwear(typeId primary key , Brandname, style , foreign key(typeid) references product)" . But that is not allowed as TypeId  repeats many times in product table

Comment: Oh, so these are tables and not types. An example would help a lot.

Comment: Product table has entries ("100","abc",72.00,"footwear", 1) and ("101","cde",90.00,"footwear", 1) . Footwear has entires (1,"Nike", casual). (2,"Puma", casual). Here different products in product table can have type 1 as their type id.

Comment: I mean a complete working test we can run ourselves, included as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Footwear ( prod_ID (PK, fk), typeId(fk), Brandname, Style)

Apparels ( prod_ID (PK, fk), typeId(fk), material, size)
```

Subtypes are subsets so we use the same identifier for them.

Comment: Yes. This will work. I was looking for a solution without using prod_Id in subTypes. But i guess that not possible as it is a subset. Thanks